# こいつ　そいつ　あいつ vs こやつ　そやつ　あやつ

Tags: word-choice, words, colloquial-language

I know they're all connected to 奴, but what's the difference? Are the forms in ～やつ more old-fashioned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, ～やつ is antiquated and one would only use it in a joking manner. E.g. `こやつが犯人です` as a caption for a funny cat pic.